# Compute the distance from a point in $\textbf{R}^3$ to Boy's surface

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, optimization

We're given a parametric surface $S\subset\textbf{R}^3$, and an arbitrary $\boldsymbol x\in\textbf{R}^3$ where $\boldsymbol x := (x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

We'd like to compute the distance from $\boldsymbol x$ to $S$.

**Note.** By *distance* I mean *smallest (Euclidean) distance*.

**Example.** Let $S\subset\textbf{R}^3$ be the image of the map

$$
\begin{align}
[0;2\pi] \times [0;\pi] & \longrightarrow \textbf{R}^3 \\
(\theta, \varphi) & \longmapsto (s_1, s_2, s_3) \\
(\theta, \varphi) & \longmapsto (\cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi),\ \sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi),\ \cos(\varphi))
\end{align}
$$

(ie. $S$ is the unit sphere centered at $\boldsymbol 0\in\textbf{R}^3$). Then the (smallest Euclidean) distance $d$ from $\boldsymbol x \in \textbf{R}^3$ to $S\subset\textbf{R}^3$, is (I think)

$$ d = |\boldsymbol x - \boldsymbol 0| - 1 = |\boldsymbol x| - 1,$$

where $|\boldsymbol a|$ is the norm of $\boldsymbol a$.

---

The case of interest is the distance from $\boldsymbol x\in\textbf{R}^3$ to the Kusner-Bryant parametrization of [**Boy's surface**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy%27s_surface) (an immersion of $\textbf{R}P^2$ inside $\textbf{R}^3$), which is a function of a complex parameter $w\in\textbf{C}$ in the complex unit disk $\textbf{D}$ (ie. $|w| \leq 1$).

Now $S\subset\textbf{R}^3$ is the image of the map

$$
\begin{align}
\textbf{D}\subset\textbf{C} & \longrightarrow \textbf{R}^3 \\
w & \longmapsto (s_1, s_2, s_3) \\
w & \longmapsto (gg_1, gg_2, gg_3)
\end{align}
$$

where

$$
\begin{align}
g1 & := -{3 \over 2} \text{Im}\left[{w(1-w^4) \over g_4}\right] \\
g2 & := -{3 \over 2} \text{Re}\left[{w(1+w^4) \over g_4}\right] \\
g3 & := \text{Im}\left[{1 + w^6 \over g_4}\right] - {1 \over 2} \\
g4 & := w^3(w^3 + \sqrt5) - 1\\
g & := {1 \over g_1^2 + g_2^2 + g_3^2}
\end{align}
$$

What is an expression for the distance from $\boldsymbol x$ to $S$?

*(An application of this is to [render the surface](http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm))*

Comment: This fact may be useful here: A minimizing path from a point to a surface intersect the surface orthogonally.

Comment: What that makes me think is that we could compute the plane $P_{\boldsymbol s}$ 
tangent to the surface $S$ at $\boldsymbol s\in S$, and then compute the distance from $\boldsymbol x$ to $P_{\boldsymbol s}$, which is easy it's the distance from a point to a plane... Or something of sorts, maybe

Comment: Nevermind, I don't think that helps, since the distance from $x$ to $P_{\boldsymbol s}$ will not be the smallest one to $S$...

Comment: I am not suggesting finding the distance to the plane. All I am saying is that the minimizing path to the *surface*, has the following property: its velocity vector (derivative) at the intersection point with the surface is orthogonal to the tangent plane of the surface.

Comment: Wait, but maybe it does help? Let $d_{P_s}$ be the distance from $\boldsymbol x$ to the plane $P_{\boldsymbol s}$ (think of the shortest vector going from $\boldsymbol x$ to $P_{\boldsymbol s}$, and call this vector $\boldsymbol v_{P_s}$). What if we then compute the distance from the "head" of the vector $v_{P_{\boldsymbol s}}$ to $\boldsymbol s$? Call this distance $d_{\boldsymbol s}$. Then the (square of the) smallest distance $d$ from $\boldsymbol x$ to $\boldsymbol s$ may be $d_{P_s}^2 + d_{\boldsymbol s}^2$...

Comment: I think what Asaf is essentially recommending is that you use Lagrange multipliers. I don't know whether Boy's surface has a nice description as a level set of a function, so this may not be the right approach.  Why not just pull back the distance function to the disc parameterizing your surface and do the standard multivarible optimization problem there?

Answer (score 3):

I am not really solving your questions, since there are a lot of nasty partial derivatives and calculations that I am not even going to try, but I believe thet are doable with a lot of patience (and pain).

Identify $\mathbf{D}$ with the closed unit ball $\overline{B(\mathbf{0},1)}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the mapping $\mathbf{f}: \overline{B(\mathbf{0},1)}\to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\mathbf{f}(w_1,w_2)=(gg_1,gg_2,gg_3)$. You want to compute
$$\min_{(w_1,w_2)\in \overline{B(\mathbf{0},1)}} \vert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{f}(w_1,w_2)\vert,$$
or equivalently, 
$$\min_{(w_1,w_2)\in \overline{B(\mathbf{0},1)}} \vert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{f}(w_1,w_2)\vert^2.$$
Since $\overline{B(\mathbf{0},1)}$ is compact, the minimum exists. If it is reached at a point $(a,b)$ in  $B(\mathbf{0},1)$, then it must be a critical point of the function $h(w_1,w_2):=\vert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{f}(w_1,w_2)\vert^2,$
which means that you need to compute $$\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial w_1}(w_1,w_2)=-2(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{f}(w_1,w_2))\cdot\frac{\partial{\mathbf{f}}}{\partial w_1}(w_1,w_2)=0,\\
\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial w_2}(w_1,w_2)=-2(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{f}(w_1,w_2))\cdot\frac{\partial{\mathbf{f}}}{\partial w_2}(w_1,w_2)=0.$$  Really painful, given the form of $\mathbf f$.

Otherwise the maximum is reached at a point on $\partial B(\mathbf{0},1)$ and so you can find it by using polar coordinates and studying the minimum of
$\varphi(\theta)=\vert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{f}(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\vert^2$ for $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$.

If the point $\mathbf{x}$ is very close to $S$, then the closest point $\mathbf{s}\in S$ to $\mathbf{x}$ will be unique and will satisfy the relation
$$ \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{\nu}(\mathbf{s})|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{s}|,$$
where $\mathbf{\nu}(\mathbf{s})$ is a unit normal to $S$ at $\mathbf{s}$ (see [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022039681900139)). 
Again to find the normal you will need to find the partial derivatives  $\frac{\partial{\mathbf{f}}}{\partial w_1}$ and $\frac{\partial{\mathbf{f}}}{\partial w_2}$ at $\mathbf{s}$ and then calculate its tensor product.